# How to use setState on deeply nested variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, setstate

I am currently saving a table in to `this.state` as you can see here

```
this.setState({    
      table: 
        <div  id='link-table' className="table-panel-table" style={{ width: "100%" , height: height - 35, overflow:'auto' }}>
          {columns}
          {rows}
        </div>      
    });
```

The `table` variable is then directly used in the render function to display on the website:

```
render(){ return (this.state.table) }
```

*(If this is a bad idea for some reason please do tell me)*

The problem I currently have is that I want to turn one of the cells in to an input field (and obviously a form element above it) when you click on it.
I would like to know how to best change `this.state.table` so that it would fire a re-render when i change the cell.

If i use this it doesn't work

```
this.state.table.props.children[1][row].props.children[cell].props.children = form_element;
```

From what I understood i need to use `this.setState()` to change it accordingly but i'm having difficulty writing the code to target the specific nested variable in `this.state.table`.

I got to

```
const { table } = this.state;
let temp_table = {...table, props: {...table.props, children: [...table.props.children]}}
```

but then get stuck because I don't know how to continue with `.children[1][row]`

Comment: Have you considered just storing the data in state, computing the JSX in the render function, then you need only store additional state for toggling the input element. Conditionally rendering JSX is a heck of lot easier then trying to update deeply nested JSX  stored in state (I've no idea why one would *want* to do this) that is likely dynamic.

Comment: Do you know the value to put in `.children[1][row]`?

Comment: @AaminKhan https://imgur.com/a/GHAszcn here is a screenshot of the table. The next variable is 'props' again if that's what you mean.

Comment: @DrewReese that actually might be a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to store the table in state, you can just store rows and columns data so that you dont have to deal with finding element inside the table. Dont store jsx elements in the state, just store data to generate the view.

```
render(){ 
  return (
    <div  id='link-table' className="table-panel-table" style={{ width: "100%" , height: height - 35, overflow:'auto' }}>
      {generateColumns(this.state.columns)}
      {generateRows(this.state.rows)}
    </div>      
)
```

}

You should also not directly manipulate dom elements to change their apperance. React's way of doing it is generating your elements with respect to their state and render different components according to their state. I don't know how you generate generate rows and columns but following approach might give an idea:

```
generateRows= (rows) => {

  return rows.map(row => { 
    if(row.shouldHaveFormElement) {
        return <RowComponentWithFormElement></RowComponentWithFormElement>
    }else {
        return <NormalRowElement></NormalRowElement>
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think i had something similar previously however from what i saw it kept running the function that populates the elements over and over again every time i resized the table, that's why i just put all the rows in to a single variable. I don't know react enough if that's better or not.

Comment: Seperating your data and your view is a nice practice and i suggest you follow it. Whenever you resize the table, render method of the table gets called but i dont think it causes a performance issue because react understands that elements are getting updated so it does not recreate the components at each render.